# How can I resize the partions, reduse /home partition, and increase the root partition without adding additional hard-drive space

Tags: linux, terminal, partition, move-partition

For Virtual Machine I'm using with VMware, and for OS the Ubuntu 20.04.
I create the `500Mb for /boot`, `30GB for root /`, `8192MB for /swap` and `others for /home` partition.
When I installed the Ubuntu, I create the partitions disks. It was like:

```
/boot = 500MB
/     = 30GB
/swap = 8192MB
/home = 15GB
```

[image]

The output after installation by using *`parted`* command it likes:

```
dev@ops:~$ sudo parted -l
Model: VMware Virtual NVMe Disk (nvme)
Disk /dev/nvme0n1: 53.7GB
Sector size (logical/physical): 512B/512B
Partition Table: msdos
Disk Flags: 

Number  Start   End     Size    Type      File system     Flags
 1      1049kB  500MB   499MB   primary   ext2            boot
 2      501MB   53.7GB  53.2GB  extended
 5      501MB   30.5GB  30.0GB  logical   ext4
 6      30.5GB  38.7GB  8191MB  logical   linux-swap(v1)
 7      38.7GB  53.7GB  15.0GB  logical   ext4
```

Now I want to resize the partitions of ***15GB*** and ***30GB***.
I want to take the ***5GB*** from partition ***Number 7***: and move it to the partition ***Number 5 (30GB)*** and merge it with a ***30GB***. After the process, it would be shows:

```
Number  Start   End     Size    Type      File system     Flags
 1      1049kB  500MB   499MB   primary   ext2            boot
 2      501MB   53.7GB  53.2GB  extended
 5      501MB   30.5GB  35.0GB  logical   ext4
 6      30.5GB  38.7GB  8191MB  logical   linux-swap(v1)
 7      38.7GB  53.7GB  10.0GB  logical   ext4
```

I don't use with the LVM methodologies, simple partitioning only.


Thank you in advance!

Comment: Use gparted livecd to move,resize your partitions as you want https://gparted.org/ shrink 7, shift 6,7 to the end, grow 5, apply

Comment: I can't use with classic way - `fdisk`, `cfdisk`, `sfdisk` or `parted` to do this? Thanks

Comment: You need to shift (move} partitions with filesystems inside it. These tools cant do this

Comment: Why you cant boot your vm from gparted iso?

Comment: That's it, it works. I had to change something in VM. This option exists only in the _VMware workstation pro_, in the normal version (Player) it does not exist. I change the _"Firmware type"_ from **BIOS** to **UEFI**. This option exist in _"Edit virtual machine settings"_ ⇾ _"Options"_ ⇾ _"Advanced"_. After that, the system loaded to the _gparted-live-cd_, and I can to change the partition size. Thank you, @gapsf!